# Application crashing with UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, appdelegate, swiftui

**Context:** My app is made using SwiftUI, which is a game using SpriteKit.

When pressing the home button on my device, my app encounters an error called '`UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError`'. The log looks like so:

> `Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.`

I have tried making the breakpoint, but it doesn't give me any helpful information I understand. There is no log, it just shows the Debug Navigator.

[image: Debug Navigator]

I tried to investigate where the issue came from. I just added some simple print statements. The print `Update` repeats a few times quickly, before the application is halted by the breakpoint:

```
struct SceneView: UIViewRepresentable {

    let bounds: CGRect


    // Conformance to UIViewRepresentable
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> SKView {
        SKView(frame: bounds)
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: SKView, context: Context) {
        print("Update")

        let scene = Scene(size: bounds.size)
        uiView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        uiView.showsFPS = true
        uiView.showsDrawCount = true
        uiView.showsNodeCount = true
        uiView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

---

- What is causing the issue, and how can I fix this?
- Could this be due to SwiftUI or my Xcode betas and iPhone betas not matching up?

Comment: Search through your code to see where you are calling `endBackgroundTask`

Comment: @Paulw11 I am not calling that from anywhere in my project

Comment: Did you set a symbolic breakpoint on UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError? If so, turn off that breakpoint.

Comment: Getting the same message when going into background running my app on iOS13. Same code for previous iOS versions does not output this error.  Think this rules out. SwiftUI being the cause though.

Comment: Agreed about SwiftUI not being the direct cause. I have a regular Swift project. Using Xcode 11 GM, I experienced the crash when returning to Home in Simulator. In Xcode 11 GM Seed 2, I no longer get the crash, but still get the warning in console.

Comment: Related thread from the apple developer forum: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121990

Answer (score 2):

It is fixed on iOS 13.2 beta 3, you can test it there, it should be fixed.

Comment: can you share source ?

Comment: Not fixed for live version of my app in 13.2.

Comment: @BilalSiddiqui sorry I didn't see your comment, now 13.2 it is not in beta any more, you can test it in the latest release iOS version. (iOS 13.2)

Comment: @SAHM weird, it is fixed for me

Comment: the same issue on `13.3.1.`